# What are escape characters to search for e.g. "p >> N"?

Tags: support

How can I search for e.g. "p >> N" -- are there escape characters, "p\>\> N" ?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but would like to point out that expressions like this are likely to be marked up in $\TeX$ and therefore would not match the special characters anyway.

Comment: Plus most formulas has some "verbalization" under which it is a better idea to look -- for instance *large p small n* for $p\gg N$.

Comment: In what sense do you want to search for this? We do have a tag for [underdetermined](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underdetermined), which we use for "p>>n".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried searching the LaTeX breakdown?

Honestly, you may be better off using Google/Bing for this type of search. Lucene doesn't really handle TeX well, in my admittedly limited experience.